# How to pass a value from ng-Init to the next controller

Tags: angularjs, singlepage

I get a `userName` when loading Index.

**MVC Controller Action**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   string userName = "Current User"
   return View((object)userName);
}
```

And then use `ng-init` to try to store the value.

**Index.html**

```
@model string
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-init="user='@Model'">  
    <body>
        <div>Welcome @Model!</div>
        <div ng-view=""></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

On the initial ng-View template, I can still render the contents of `{{user}}`. but what I want is to pull it into the first angular controller so that I can pass it on throughout the life of the application so I don't have to query the server for it again.

I thought something like this would work in the first template to render:

```
<div ng-init="vm.username='{{user}}'>
```

with a controller that has `$scope.username`. That clearly doesn't work I believe because of the order of how Angular renders.

Any good ideas on how I can hold on to that username value through the life of the application if this won't work?

Comment: You can always put things in the $rootScope or, more preferably, in a service. These are singletons that live throughout the lifetime of the application.

Comment: Angular really works best if you write the backend as an API that uses JSON request/response body.  As mentioned above you could also insert the value into a provider like a factory/service/value and then inject that into any other controllers or providers that need the value.  This looks pertinent https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html  Also the scopes that are made for particular elements is generally inherited from parent to child unless the directive makes an isolate scope, in any case the provider is a more surefire way to inject the appropriate value.

Comment: Yes, it is written that way, with Web APIs that provide the data. OK, so injecting a service seems like the way I should go. If one of you will put that in an answer, I will mark it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
@model string
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">  
    <body ng-init="user='@Model'">
        <div>Welcome @Model!</div>
        <div ng-view=""></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does this do? I still can't do anything more than display {{user}} in the other templates. I need to be able to reference it in another controller.